# Where does the concept of Midah K'neged Midah come in during the 10 plagues?

Tags: egypt

Seemingly the punishment for not allowing the jews to leave should have been some sort of midah kneged midah. Is that found somewhere withing the ten plagues?

Comment: Yes, there's so much. May I recommend "Let My Nation Go" by Yosef Deutsch who uses midrash and aggadata to tell the whole story in prose, and along the way explains all the countless examples of midda k'negged midda, with sources. Are you asking specifically just about the injustice of not allowing them to leave?

Comment: Although p'sukim allude to this regarding multiple plagues, one example is mentioned explicitly in the verse ([Sh'mos 4:23](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0204.htm#23)): "וָאֹמַר אֵלֶיךָ שַׁלַּח אֶת בְּנִי וְיַעַבְדֵנִי וַתְּמָאֵן לְשַׁלְּחוֹ הִנֵּה אָנֹכִי הֹרֵג אֶת בִּנְךָ בְּכֹרֶךָ".

Comment: The last plague seems the most obvious

Answer (score 3):

Midrash Tanchuma Va’eira 13-14; Bo 4 links each plague to something the Egyptians did wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the Zohar there, which explains some of the plagues this way

Comment: Could you please include an exact reference to that Zohar?